# How to capture current timerange

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

Goal 
I have to query table 1 and join with table 2 entries.

Note:-Events in table 2 happen before table 1 so I want to ensure that when I query table 2 the startTime is less than 1 day or few hours.

however it seems I cannot pass the timecontext. I have tried a few ways but failed.

```
let minTime = customEvents | summarize min(timestamp) by appId | project min_timestamp;
let startTime = toscalar(minTime);

customEvents
 | where timestamp <= todatetime(startTime) 
 | take 10 ;
```

the above query for example only returns me the very first entry in the table.

Comment: Please elaborate more on your ASK,  what type of query you need it , i am assuming you need KQL query ? Where do you want to access timestamp? Is it in Azure Data Explorer in application insight?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following approach:

```
let customEvents = datatable(appId: string, timestamp:datetime, message:string)
[
    "A", datetime(2019-03-08 16:14:50), "Hello from 'A'",
    "A", datetime(2019-03-08 15:14:50), "Hello from 'A'",
    "A", datetime(2019-03-08 14:14:50), "Hello from 'A'",
    "A", datetime(2019-03-08 13:14:50), "Hello from 'A'",
    "B", datetime(2019-03-08 12:14:50), "Hello from 'B'",
    "B", datetime(2019-03-08 11:14:50), "Hello from 'B'",    
    "D", datetime(2019-03-08 10:14:50), "Hello from 'D'",
    "C", datetime(2019-03-08 09:14:50), "Hello from 'C'",    
    "D", datetime(2019-03-08 08:14:50), "Hello from 'D'",
    "C", datetime(2019-03-08 07:14:50), "Hello from 'C'",    
]
;
let minTimeByAppId = toscalar(
    customEvents 
    | summarize min(timestamp) by appId 
    | summarize make_bag(pack(appId, min_timestamp)))
;
let otherTable = datatable(appId:string, timestamp:datetime, otherMessage:string)
[
    "A", datetime(2019-03-08 16:14:50), "Another hello from 'A'",
    "A", datetime(2019-03-07 16:14:50), "Another hello from 'A'",
    "B", datetime(2019-03-07 16:14:50), "Another hello from 'B'",
    "B", datetime(2019-03-08 16:14:50), "Another hello from 'B'",
    "C", datetime(2019-03-08 16:14:50), "Another hello from 'C'",
    "C", datetime(2019-03-08 16:14:50), "Another hello from 'C'",
    "D", datetime(2019-03-09 16:14:50), "Another hello from 'D'",
    "D", datetime(2019-03-08 16:14:50), "Another hello from 'D'",
]
;
otherTable
| where timestamp < minTimeByAppId[appId] // you could also add some 'delta' here
```

which will output:

```
| appId | timestamp                   | otherMessage           |
|-------|-----------------------------|------------------------|
| A     | 2019-03-07 16:14:50.0000000 | Another hello from 'A' |
| B     | 2019-03-07 16:14:50.0000000 | Another hello from 'B' |
```